# Is Xubuntu as power-efficient as Ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, power-management

I'm wondering if Xubuntu has the same features as Ubuntu 12.04

Particularly I'm trying to get the most battery life out of my laptop. Does Xubuntu 12.04 feature the same improvements to power management that come default in Ubuntu 12.04?

In general, is the difference between Xubuntu and Ubuntu simply the DE? Is all the underlying improvements available in both distros?

Comment: I think Xubuntu will be more battery-saving then ubuntu, since it requires less RAM to run.

Comment: In that way, you could argue that lighter = more power savings, but thats not really what I'm talking about - and my experience has shown openbox distros like Crunchbang performing poorly simply because Debian hadn't done much for powersavings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xubuntu uses the same kernel as Ubuntu, as well as the same low-level power management utilities (*hdparm*, etc.), so yes, it has the same *power management capabilities* as Ubuntu.

**But**, Xubuntu *may* be *more* power-efficient than Ubuntu on your laptop, primarily because it's a "lightweight" desktop environment; it places somewhat less load on both your CPU and GPU compared to Ubuntu (Unity 3D). Whether it saves power over Ubuntu (and how much) depends on your specific hardware and use patterns.

Comment: In particular, I hear ubuntu has done some work with pm-utils and power.d to script more devices to shut off or go into low power mode sooner. Would this be carried over into Xubuntu?

Comment: Yes, Xubuntu uses the *same* low-level (CLI) utilities as Ubuntu, including `pm-utils`, `power.d`, etc. The only difference is the DE, which frankly consists of simply the `xubuntu-desktop` package.