# How do I switch between Xubuntu and Ubuntu, based on convenience?

Tags: xubuntu

I know how to install Xubuntu, i.e. by:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

I've used Xubuntu, and it's pretty lightweight and [is power efficient than Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/164067/835885). But on the other hand, it does take away the looks of Ubuntu. So, obviously, I wanted to use Ubuntu when I've no limit on power usage (laptop is connected), and Xubuntu when there is a limit (laptop on battery).

So, is there a way to switch back and forth between Xubuntu and Ubuntu, based on convenience?

Comment: Why do you believe that there's any measurable difference what so ever in how much power is used?

Answer (score 3):

#### Ubuntu 17.10 and later (Gnome)

On login screen, click wrench icon and select your favour DE.

[image]

<sub>Taken from [linuxconfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-xubuntu-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)</sub>

#### Ubuntu 17.04 and below (Unity)

On login screen, click Ubuntu icon and select your DE.

[image]

<sub>Taken from [tecmint.com](https://www.tecmint.com/install-xfce-desktop-in-ubuntu-fedora/)</sub>

Comment: But does this still bring in some auto-run programs from the default Ubuntu session in XFCE session? If yes, then the objective of being more power efficient (as efficient as a default Xubuntu) may be not met.